# New column based on 1 condition using index and one column groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, conditional-statements

Example subset of df:

```
                Category    Weight  Test
1/21/2017       SuperMarket 0.02    Nan
1/21/2017       SuperMarket 0.18    Nan
1/21/2017       SuperMarket 0.71    Nan
1/21/2017       Hotel       0.53    Nan
1/21/2017       Hotel       0.93    0.93
1/21/2017       Hotel       0.97    Nan
1/21/2017       Bar         0.13    Nan
1/21/2017       Bar         0.31    Nan
1/21/2017       Bar         0.96    Nan
1/21/2017       Bar         0.65    0.65
1/21/2017       Bar         0.27    0.27
1/21/2017       Bar         0.24    Nan
1/21/2017       Hospital    0.65    0.65
1/21/2017       Hospital    0.90    0.90
1/21/2017       Hospital    1.00    1.00
```

New column `df['Adjusted_weight']` which will be assigned values based on 3 conditions:

1. If for any date and category `df['Test']` contains only Nans, then `df['Adjusted_weight'] = df['weight']`
2. If for any date and category `df['Test']` contains only values (no Nans), then `df['Adjusted_weight'] = df['weight']`
3. Lastly, if for any date and category, if `df['Test']` contains both values and Nans, then:

i) For where `df['Test'] = Nan`, then `df['Adjusted_weight'] = df['weight'] * 0.5`

ii) For where `df['Test'] = value`, then `df['Adjusted_weight'] = df['weight'] + SUM (df['weight'] - df['adjusted_weight'] )` `/ number of non Nan values` number of non Nans there are* for the NaNs.

In part ii), we are up-scaling the adjusted weights where there are values so that the sum of the adjusted weight(in part 3), is equal to the sum of the weights (for a particular date and category).

Example output:

```
                Category    Weight  Test    Adjusted Weight
1/21/2017       SuperMarket 0.02    Nan        0.02
1/21/2017       SuperMarket 0.18    Nan        0.18
1/21/2017       SuperMarket 0.71    Nan        0.71
1/21/2017       Hotel       0.53    Nan        0.265
1/21/2017       Hotel       0.93    0.93       1.68
1/21/2017       Hotel       0.97    Nan        0.485
1/21/2017       Bar         0.13    Nan        0.07
1/21/2017       Bar         0.31    Nan        0.16
1/21/2017       Bar         0.96    Nan        0.48
1/21/2017       Bar         0.65    0.65       1.06
1/21/2017       Bar         0.27    0.27       0.68
1/21/2017       Bar         0.24    Nan        0.12
1/21/2017       Hospital    0.65    0.65       0.65
1/21/2017       Hospital    0.90    0.90       0.90
1/21/2017       Hospital    1.00    1.00       1.00
```

An example of how I populated **Hotel** for **1/21/2007**. Where there are 2 Nans and 1 value. So for the 2 Nans, in adjusted weight, it was just `df['weight'] * 0.5` .

Now for where there was one value, it is simply `0.93 + (0.53 - 0.265) + (0.97 - 0.485)` which = `1.68` .

***JUST ADDED SECTION***

For the example of **Bar** , There are 4 Nan values which `df['Adjusted weight'] = 0.5* df['weight']` . Now there are two values for 1/21/2017 Bar. They both need weights to be added to df['adjusted_weight'] so that the sum is equal to the df['weight'] for 1/21/2017 Bar. Therefore the calculation is (0.13 -0.07) + (0.31-0.16) + (0.96 - 0.48) + (0.24-0.12) = 0.82, as there are two values to distribute to, 0.41 would be added to 0.65 and 0.27 which equals 1.06 and 0.68 .

We may have any amount of Nans and values, or only Nans and only values.

The underlying objective is to scale up within date and category where there are values, and to ensure the weight in that box (date, category), is the same as it was before.

I have many dates, and the data is much larger than displayed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a function that you pass to `apply` after grouping to do all your calculations.

```
def f(x):
    count = x.Test.count()
    size = x.Test.size
    if count == 0 or count == size:
        return x.Weight
    else:
        adj_null = x.Weight * x.Test.isnull() * .5
        notnull = x.Test.notnull()
        distribute = adj_null.sum() / notnull.sum()
        adj_notnull = (x.Weight + distribute) * notnull
        return adj_null + adj_notnull

df['Adjusted Weight'] = df.groupby([pd.TimeGrouper('D'), 'Category'], sort=False).apply(f).values

               Category  Weight  Test  Adjusted Weight
2017-01-21  SuperMarket    0.02   NaN            0.020
2017-01-21  SuperMarket    0.18   NaN            0.180
2017-01-21  SuperMarket    0.71   NaN            0.710
2017-01-21        Hotel    0.53   NaN            0.265
2017-01-21        Hotel    0.93  0.93            1.680
2017-01-21        Hotel    0.97   NaN            0.485
2017-01-21          Bar    0.13   NaN            0.065
2017-01-21          Bar    0.31   NaN            0.155
2017-01-21          Bar    0.96   NaN            0.480
2017-01-21          Bar    0.65  0.65            1.060
2017-01-21          Bar    0.27  0.27            0.680
2017-01-21          Bar    0.24   NaN            0.120
2017-01-21     Hospital    0.65  0.65            0.650
2017-01-21     Hospital    0.90  0.90            0.900
2017-01-21     Hospital    1.00  1.00            1.000
```

Comment: This is groupby category only? There are multiple dates (need groypby date and category)

Comment: You can add `pd.TimeGrouper` to groupby a date in the index. Also, I think your calculation for the Bar category is off for the non-na values.

Comment: No the values are correct, I have added to the question how I calculate the example for Bar for 1/21/2017. Essentially you are restributing the weight across at all locations where there is a value in Test for the particular date and category.

Comment: Ok. I've updated the logic to redistribute the null values accordingly.

Comment: For a larger data set it does not seem to work where there are many more columns ....trying to understand why

Comment: Ignore last comment :)